# how to create application which support video call?

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, video-capture, ipod-touch, cfnetwork

i want to create application which support video call using Wi-Fi/3g network connection.

i don't have any idea from where i can start. please suggest me  somethings.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Record some video, package them into small tcp/ip packages and transfer them over the net.
basic question basic answer.

Comment: but i saw application which provide video calling like tango

Comment: hmm really… strange… maybe because they are not as much users as Apple or Skype would have, I don't know. Ok you persuades me :)